# task executed slowly after celery serving for long time but still work quickly after celery restart

Tags: celery

This kind of issues occurs several times

[image: celery serves for long time]

The log shows that when celery serves for a long time, there was a stuck about 50s. I dont know what happened in that "break"

[image: after celery restart]

But it works properly after restarting celery and indeed this task only consumes less than 10s

I suppose there was something overloaded in the backend of celery then be released after restart.

But I have no idea what's the real problem and hardly come up with such issue

Comment: I am fairly certain it has nothing to do with Celery. Most common culprit is that machine starts swapping or something similar... So I suggest you to monitor memory usage on these nodes.

Comment: @DejanLekic Thanks for your respond. You mean memory leak? I have observed the memory usage and the celery process indeed occupied more memory than the beginning, but I dont know why and what took away the memory